# Sql query showing additional results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have

```
 SELECT s.* 
  FROM shop 
 WHERE s.family IN (SELECT s2.family FROM shop s2 WHERE (s2.money like "%k%"))
```

it does return "ticket" which contanis the k letter but in addition it returns all the other results that doesn't have "k" in it

here is the table of shop :

```
+----+--------+-------+
| id | family | money |
+----+--------+-------+
|  1 |      1 |  card |
|  2 |      1 |Cheque |
|  3 |      2 |coins  |
|  4 |      2 |ticket |    
+----+--------+-------+
```

i am using

```
 IN (SELECT s2.family FROM shop s2 WHERE (s2.money like "%k%"));
```

because i want to show the results as a group of rows with the same family, i got this query from an other question

Comment: it does not make sense to compare a number as a string..

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: what other results are those, then? Show us a sample of the source data and the expected result. What you are claiming seems a little unlikely, to be honest.

Comment: it's just an exampl money is actually a text i just named it like this

Comment: you say `"money" is actually a text`...where is "money" in your code above? There's no such thing mentioned. What are you referring to? Please give us information which is a) clear, b) complete and c) accurate, otherwise we are going to have a lot of trouble understanding you and helping you. Thanks.

Comment: BTW the subquery here seems entirely redundant - why can't you just do `WHERE value = `...etc in the outer query? You're just querying the same table again.

Comment: i updated my question sorry for not being so clear

Comment: Your query cannot be working because there is no field called value in your table

Comment: And you really don't need a sub query, it's pointless.

Comment: Where does your alias `s` comes from?  I don't see `s` declared anywhere.

Comment: Debugging is part of programmer's job.  Have you tried to run only the subquery and see what it returns??? `SELECT s2.family FROM shop s2 WHERE (s2.money like "%k%")`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM shop 
WHERE money LIKE "%text%";
```

You are using a statement from a previous question you posted that might not be valid in this situation.

Comment: Meaning? You want to group by family what?

Comment: @jason9 what do you mean by family exactly? Edit the question to show your desired output, it's not very clear what you mean. Normally if you group by it's because you want to count the records, or sum a values column, or similar. Do you want to count the matching records in each family? Have you studied group by queries in SQL? It would be quite a simple one...you should find a tutorial and try it maybe. You learn a lot more that way. If you're still stuck then we could help you more